# How to say "Say hi to someone" as a description?

Tags: grammar

So, I've been trying to figure out what is the best way to describe the sentence "I went to the store to say hi to the owner". (Imagine in this context I haven't seen him for a certain amount of time, so I'd like to go in and just quickly say "hi" and then leave)
Do people say  “跟他说你好？” 
比如 “我最后决定去跟那个老板说你好。”

Comment: I'm sorry but what does **the story** mean here? I know it doesn't affect my answer below - but I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out what it means and I can only guess that it's an iDevice autocorrect...

Comment: @user3306356 I think it's meant to be "I went to the store" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be say " 我只是去那个店里和老板打了个招呼".

say "只是" to point the mean of 「just quickly say "hi" and then leave」

Answer (score 5):

“Say hi to someone” in Chinese is just a simple `打招呼` (unless you mean "please say hi to so-and-so for me - then it's 问好).

so what you want to say here is: `我跟老板打了个招呼....`